# In MVC how can I return to view and dislay an error message based on database condition?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I feel like this should be easy... but I am having trouble. I need to compare a value entered by the user to a value that exists in my database. If "available" is less than the value requested by the user, the request should terminate and display an error message. My POST action has an if statement like this:

```
var cardcollection = new CardCollection { CardCollectionID = 0, CollectionID = 0, CardID = 0, NumberofCopies = 0, Wishlist = 0, Available = 0, InDecks = 0 };
cardcollection = db.CardCollections.Where(c => c.CardID.Equals(cardid)).Where(d => d.CollectionID.Equals(collectionid)).First();

int num = number.NumberToAdd;
int copies = cardcollection.NumberofCopies;
int available = cardcollection.Available;
if (num > available)
{
   // Pass message "Cannot add more than is available in your collection";
   //return View(GO BACK TO CREATE VIEW);
}

available = copies - num;
int used = cardcollection.InDecks;
int indecks = used + num;
int id = cardcollection.CardCollectionID;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    db.CardDecks.Add(carddeck);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
var cardavailability = String.Format("Update CardCollections Set InDecks = {0}, available = {1} Where CardCollectionID = {2}", indecks, available, id);
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(cardavailability);
db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Details", "Deck", new { id = deckid });
```

I can't use the ModelState.IsValid because it is already valid.

Comment: Why don't you use the ViewBag to set your message and re-display the same view?

Comment: where is your number object being pulled

Comment: Just add a `ModelState` error and return the view - `if (num > available) { ModelState.AddModelError("", "Cannot add more than is available in your collection"); return View(yourModel); }`

Answer (score 2):

What about using ModelState.AddModelError:

```
if (num > available)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("MyError","Cannot add more than is available in your collection");
    return  View(GO BACK TO CREATE VIEW);
}
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("MyError")
```

Comment: I think that works, but I can't get it to return to the create view. In my Create controller I create a view model. When I try to do the same thing in the POST it errors because the AddCardstoDeck model is already being passed. The view model I want is  `var createview = new AddCardstoDeck(card, carddeck, deck);
            carddeck.CardID = id;
            carddeck.DeckID = deck.DeckID;  
            return View(createview);`